# UICollectionView jumps on manual scroll after scrollToItem set (Swift)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I managed to get my `UICollectionView` to set to the desired position using

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: itemIndex, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
}
```

but, for example, if I slide left from the right hand side, it slides, but then the `UIImage` jumps back to the right,  before sliding left properly. This happens with or without paging enabled (I'm using paging).

Is there something else I should be setting?

Comment: relevant  but when overriding a method don't forget `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: itemIndex, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
```

should be outside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as it's called for every layout draw which calls the same line and causes the flickers , so try it inside `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear`

Comment: Hi @Sh_Khan thank you. Using `viewWillAppear` causes strange visual results. However, using `viewDidAppear` works, but now I see the first image for a second or two before the required image appears. Is there any way to resolve this new issue?

Comment: change `at: .centeredHorizontally` to `at: .bottom ` ?

Comment: `.bottom` and `.top` don't show the required image at all, whereas `.left`, `.right`, and .`centreHorizontally` still delay the image change. Note using `viewWillAppear` also doesn't change the image to the one I want, but also makes the image it does display the wrong size.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem using a boolean flag and `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, thus

```
var layoutDone: Bool = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if(!layoutDone) {

        layoutDone = true

        collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: itemIndex, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
}
```